# Form_for method to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers. `Pages` and `Tasks`. And in views/pages I want to make form for `Tasks` controller and `new` action.

I tried this:

```
<%= form_for @task, url: url_for(controller: 'tasks', action: 'new') do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

But I get an error in my browser:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty:

This is how look like my `Tasks` controller's `new` method:

```
  def new
    @task = Task.new
    @task.done = false
    if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Success"
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Error"
    end
  end
```

Of course there isn't the `@task` variable in Pages/new.
So how to tell Rails to look for this variable in Tasks controller?

Comment: Solved. I change `new` action to `create` action and works fine. A little wired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your @task is nil. You should initialise it in the action whose view you are rendering or else just use `form_for Task`. It should work. Hope it helps

Comment: No. When I add `@task = Task.new` to my `Pages` controller and `home` action it is OK (form is in `views/pages/home.erb.html`). So Rails looking for `@task` variable in Pages not in Tasks controller. And I don't know how to change it.